# ObjectStateEntry has the State "Added" whereas the respective entity is "Unchanged"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

We use EF5 for user management and have a simple one-to-many relation between `Users` and `Partners`, whereas both classes are self-tracking entity classes.

[image: User-partner relationship]

While adding new users to the database we create a new user entity and check if the partner entity already exists in the database and set the Partner accordingly.

```
var user = new User {
   Partner = userRepository.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PartnerCode == partnerCode) };
```

Now, when we perform `SaveChanges` we face the problem that the `ObjectStateManager` returns an `ObjectStateEntry` for the `Partner` instance with `State` property set to `Added`:

[image: ObjectStateEntry]

It is unclear why this state is set to `Added`, because if we just follow the `Entity` property of the `ObjectStateEntry` object to navigate to the original entity, we'll see that it still has the status `Unchanged`:

[image]

This leads to the problem that the partner entity is written to the database even if it already exists there that is very annoying.

Any suggestions that might be wrong here?

Comment: I strongly suspect more than one context is in use here, but you don't show enough code to be sure. Don't use more than one context for this type of code. Also, you should probably have a DB-level constraint preventing exact duplicate partners.

Comment: @CraigStuntz, a collegue of mine has a similar suggestion, that the original context is destroyed and recreated in-between. We are using a DI-container for context management that complicates debugging, but I am trying to verify this idea right now.